# Pourquoi utiliser le conditionnel : « Elle aimerait… » ?

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical, conditionnel

J'ai vu cette phrase dans le cours

> Elle aimerait aller voir le ballet « Le Lac des Cygnes » depuis que ce dernier est à la mode.

Mais, je regrette, je ne comprends pas bien, même si j'ai cherché les mots dans le dictionnaire.  Est-ce que vous pouvez m'aider ?

1. Pourquoi c'est *Elle aimerait...* — le conditionnel présent ? Qu'est-ce que ça veut dire, en anglais ?  Et la première fois que je l'ai entendu, je pense que la phrase était *elle aimait...*, mais c'est faux.
2. Est-ce que ça veut dire *depuis que ce dernier est à la mode*?  C'est « since the last time it was in vogue » en anglais ?

Comment: “ce dernier” is ”Le Lac des Cygnes”, just a fancy (and a bit stilted) way to say “it”. So “[…] depuis qu'il est à la mode” would mean the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

L'utilisation du conditionnel exprime, dans ce cas, le souhait d'aller voir le ballet.

En anglais, on pourrait dire : « She would like to ... »

> « depuis que ce dernier est à la mode »

peut se traduire par :

> « since this one is in vogue ».

Comment: (+1) By contrast, “elle aimait” would suggest she does it regularly.